# operators cannot be applied to a float,'android.widget.EditText'

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple calculator and for the -/+ button i write the code bellow:

```
float ab=-1;
this.txtScreen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtScreen);
unary=(Button)findViewById(R.id.plusminus);
        mod=(Button)findViewById(R.id.modul);

        unary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtScreen.setText(ab*txtScreen);
            }
        });
```

and showing me error * operator cannot applied to float.

Comment: Well, what's the type of `txtScreen`, and what do you think it means to multiply that by a `float`? (Hint: I don't think it's the `float` that's the problem...)

Comment: Is `txtScreen` is EditText or String value ?

Comment: txtscrren is EditText

Comment: @FajarKhan hey try the below code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (it needs string):

```
    float ab=-1;


    unary=(Button)findViewById(R.id.plusminus); 
    mod=(Button)findViewById(R.id.modul); 

    unary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtScreen.setText(String.valueOf(ab * Float.valueOf(txtScreen.getText().toString())));
            } 
        });
```

Edit: Getting the value from the txtScreen in calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
float ab=-1;

unary=(Button)findViewById(R.id.plusminus);
        mod=(Button)findViewById(R.id.modul);
unary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtScreen.setText(String.valueOf(ab*Float.parseFloat(txtScreen.getText().toString())));
            }
        });
```